build Nar for Python processor NIFI 2.0.0-M4
i am trying to create python processor for NIFI 2.0.0-M4 using python 3.12, i want to build the nar for python processor with the help of hatch and hatch-datavolo-nar package with all dependencies bundled in nar.
I have created python project with command
 hatch new trainer
then added processor .py file into src/trainer and this my pyproject.toml file

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling", "hatch-datavolo-nar"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"


[project]
name = "trainer"
dynamic = ["version"]
description = "Simple trainer processor"  
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
license = "MIT"
keywords = ["trainer"]  
authors = [
  { name = "U.N. Owen", email = "void@some.where" },
]

dependencies = ["neuralprophet", "numpy", "pandas",]  

[tool.hatch.version]
path = "src/trainer/__about__.py"


[tool.hatch.build.targets.nar]
packages = ["src/trainer"]

i am trying to build with
hatch build --target nar
but getting error at NAR-INF dependencies bundling
Processing dependencies...
Loading dependencies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(hatchling())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\cli\__init__.py", line 26, in hatchling
    command(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\cli\build\__init__.py", line 82, in build_impl
    for artifact in builder.build(
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatchling\builders\plugin\interface.py", line 155, in build
    artifact = version_api[version](directory, **build_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatch_datavolo_nar\builder.py", line 115, in build_standard
    self.process_dependencies(build_directory, nar)
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatch_datavolo_nar\builder.py", line 125, in process_dependencies
    self.install_dependencies(dependencies_dir, cache_dir)
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\hatch\env\virtual\neuralprophet\IXYHy4qS\neuralprophet-build\Lib\site-packages\hatch_datavolo_nar\builder.py", line 163, in install_dependencies
    check_call(install_arguments, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False)
  File "C:\Users\ayush.raj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\ayush.raj\\AppData\\Local\\hatch\\env\\virtual\\neuralprophet\\IXYHy4qS\\neuralprophet-build\\Scripts\\python.EXE', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'neuralprophet', 'numpy', 'pandas', '--upgrade', '--no-python-version-warning', '--no-input', '--cache-dir', "'C:\\Users\\ayush.raj\\Desktop\\POCs\\new\\pyproject\\trainer\\dist/pip-cache'", '--quiet', '--target', "'C:\\Users\\ayush.raj\\Desktop\\POCs\\new\\pyproject\\trainer\\dist\\NAR-INF\\bundled-dependencies'"]' returned non-zero exit status 2.

NOTE: if i am putting dependencies as empty in .toml file then it is successfully building nar
I am expecting nar to be geberated with all bundled dependencies of processor

If you have a solution, then wouldn't this be more appropriate as a bug report for the nar project?

i am new to this, so i don't have solution

But didn't you say "it is successfully building nar?"

Yes, when i am not putting any python dependencies in pyproject.toml file
but i want all the dependencies bundled into that nar as NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies

i don't see any clear error message in output. from errorerror i see that  pip install called with  --quiet parameter that is probably hiding the error. try to manually execute the commandline from the last line of error. try to replace --quiet with --verbose.

This PR might resolve things -- https://github.com/datavolo-io/hatch-datavolo-nar/pull/11
